# Trouble saving custom fields onto custom element type

Tags: plugins, elementtype

Im working on a plugin with a custom element type and i have most things working but i haven't been able to get custom fields to save with my elements using setContentFromPost.

I have the record and the model all setup and saving, and it creates rows in both the custom table (inquiries) as well as an entry in the craft_elements table and the craft_content tables but the craft_content table always has blanks for all the fields

I tracked things down to this one line

```
$inquiry->setContentFromPost('fields');
```

thats where its supposted to copy all the values from the post variables for fields into the element but i tested it with var dumps both before and after that line and the content isnt attached.

I did the same check in the example "Events" plugin from pixel and tonic and it is in fact that line that attaches the custom field values to that line.

I've also checked the post variable 'fields' and its set properly and its returning an array as expected with content

```
array(4) { ["jobTitle"]=> string(7) "partner" ["bio"]=> string(47) "
this is a guy

" ["twitter"]=> string(13) "@keithmancuso" ["instagram"]=> string(11) "keithmancuo" }
```

I even went so far to try and manually attach content to the model and THAT WORKS!  so when i do this:

```
    $fields = craft()->request->getPost('fields');
    $inquiry->getContent()->jobTitle = $fields['jobTitle'];
```

*It works*, job title is saved into the content table, huzza!

but why doesnt

```
    $inquiry->setContentFromPost('fields');
```

work for all the fields in the "fields" array.  Do i need to do my own loop around that array?